# Why SQL MATCH query is not working through java

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I am trying to search sql data through java to fetch searched data and insert into javafx tableview

when i run this query in sql terminal its giving result

```
select * from InvoiceNumbers where match (InvNumber,CustomerName) Against ('INV');
```

But when i run this query through javafx Its not returning any data
if i search with invoice number ,

its giving result only when i search with CustomerName

```
public void searchBtnOnAction(ActionEvent event)
{
    allReportsTableView.getItems().clear();
    String searchVal = searchTxt.getText();
    //String getSearchData = "SELECT * FROM InvoiceNumbers WHERE ((InvNumber = '"+searchVal+"') or (CustomerName like '%"+searchVal+"%')) ";
    String getSearchData="select * from InvoiceNumbers where match (InvNumber,CustomerName) Against ('"+searchVal+"')";

    try
    {
        Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
        ResultSet searchSet = statement.executeQuery(getSearchData);
        if (searchSet.next() == false)
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Data not matched");
            String s = "Incorrect Customer Name or Invoice Number";
            alert.setContentText(s);
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
        else
        {
            while (searchSet.next())
            {
                String invoice_ID = searchSet.getString("InvNumber");
                String customer_name = searchSet.getString("CustomerName");
                Double totalAmount = searchSet.getDouble("TotalAmount");
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(searchSet.getDate("Date"));
                System.out.println("test"+invoice_ID);
                System.out.println("test"+customer_name);
                System.out.println("test"+totalAmount);
                System.out.println("test"+date);
                InvoiceList invoiceListSearch = new InvoiceList(invoice_ID,customer_name,totalAmount,date);
                allReportsTableView.getItems().add(invoiceListSearch);

            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getCause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that you're skipping the first element if you have results? You're calling `next()` in the if statement and then again in the while before reading data. I assume that searching by invoice number returns exactly one element and that one is skipped.

Comment: This code is a security leak. Look up 'SQL injection'. You must use a PreparedStatement. Also, your error handling is disastrous; `e.getCause()` does nothing. just add `throws` clauses to your method declarations, and failing that, the right catch block is `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);`.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: Thanks a lot bro I will use throws in my method